# How to duplicate an array based on a condition using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that picks from the database the staff_id and display them randomly in a table.

But I want to duplicate the array based on the staff_level, such that junior staffs will be duplicated while senior staff will not be duplicated.

This is to make the Junior staffs appear twice than the senior staff. This is the code:

```
foreach ($invigilator_array_indexes as $array_index) {
            if ($row['level'] == 1){
                $invi_array = $invigilators[$array_index]['staffid_pdo'].', ';
                $output .=$invi_array;
                $output .=$invi_array.concat();
            }else {
                $invi_array = $invigilators[$array_index]['staffid_pdo'].', ';
                $output .=$invi_array;
            }

    }
```

Please note:

```
foreach ($invigilator_array_indexes as $array_index) {
                $invi_array = $invigilators[$array_index]['staffid_pdo'].', ';
                $output .=$invi_array;
    }
```

outputs the staff_id in a random order originally

All help is welcome and will be appreciated. Thank you in anticipation

full code:

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;


$records_per_page = 50;

$from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page;

include_once 'includes/config.php';
include_once 'includes/data.inc_course.php';
include 'includes/shuffle2.php';


$database = new Config();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new Data($db);

$stmt = $product->readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

//range declaration
$range = $_POST['range'];

?>



<?php include('includes/header.php'); 



$output1 = "

    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>";

        echo $output1;

       include('includes/nav.php');

$output2 = "
       <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id='page-wrapper'>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                        <h1 class='page-header'>Timetable Details</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->

                    <!-- niyicode -->
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <p>
                        <a class='btn btn-primary' href='courses/add.php' role='button'>Add Course</a>
                        <a class='btn btn-primary fleft' href='staff/add.php' role='button'>Add Staff</a>
                    </p>";
        echo $output2;

        if($num>0){
            if($range>0){


            $query1 = "SELECT staffid_pdo,level FROM staff_list WHERE avail_pdo = 1 ORDER BY id_pdo ASC ";



            $invi_stmt = $db->prepare($query1);
            $invi_stmt->execute();
            $invigilators = $invi_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //generate an array containing the range of keys in the invigilators resultset we got above
            $invigilators_array_range = range(0, (count($invigilators) - 1));

$output =  "           
        <table class= 'table table-bordered table-hover table-striped js-serial' id='printTable'>
            <caption>Timetable with number of students</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr class='success'>
                    <th style='width: 4%'>#</th>
                    <th>No. Students</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>Venue</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Invigilator</th>
                    <!-- <th>Edit/Del</th> -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>

";
        // echo $output;


while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row);


    $invigilators_needed = round(($row['snb_pdo'] / $range), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    print_r($invigilators_needed);
    $date_active = $row['dat_pdo'];

    $output .= ' <tr>' ;
    $output .= '' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['snb_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['coscd_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$date_active.'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['starttim_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['endtim_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['ven_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>'.$row['dur_pdo'].'</td>' ;
    $output .= '   <td>';

    $invigilator_array_indexes = array_rand($invigilators_array_range, $invigilators_needed);

    if (count($invigilator_array_indexes)) {
        foreach ($invigilator_array_indexes as $array_index) {
                if ($row['level'] == 1){
                    $invi_array = $invigilators[$array_index]['staffid_pdo'].', ';
                    $output .=$invi_array;
                    $output .=$invi_array.clone();
                }else {
                    $invi_array = $invigilators[$array_index]['staffid_pdo'].', ';
                    $output .=$invi_array;
                }

                print_r($invi_array);

        }

    } else $output .= "
        <div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>
           Not enough <strong>invigilators!</strong>
        </div>
        ";
    $output .= '</td>' ;
    // Add more here if appropriate .... ;
    $output .= ' </tr>' ;
?>
                    <?php
// }
}
$output .='      </tbody>
    </table>    
';
$results->free();
mysqli_close($mysqli);
echo $output;


$page_dom = "index.php";
include_once 'includes/pagination.inc_course.php';
?>

<center><button onclick="printData();" class="btn btn-primary hideprint"> Print </button></center>
<br/>

<?php
//range ending
    } else {
        ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <strong>Warning!</strong> No valid range entered. Please enter a valid range <a href="staff/range.php"> here! </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
<?php
//if num ending
}
else{
?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <strong>Warning!</strong> No Data. Please add data to view timetable
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
<?php   
$output5 = "                       </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    ";
        echo $output5;


?>
<!-- echo $output;                     -->
    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: `$duplicatedArray = $originalArray`

Comment: @Nordenheim please explain, array is a confusing topic to me

Comment: Post the full code, not partial. What's in `$invigilator_array_indexes`, `$row`, `$invigilators`?

Comment: @Bankzilla I have added the full code

Comment: You never showed what was in the above values. Also I would recommend not using `extract()`, you aren't even using any of the variables that come out of it. Looks like you just need to do basic debugging to see what information you have before targeting.

Comment: Also what Nordenheim is getting at, `$dupe = $staff['junior']; $staff['junior_duped'] = $dupe;`